removing values in pandas according to condition
In pandas dataframe I want to remove the row with duplicate employee id but accoridng to the condition where the salary is null
my original data is
  EEID      Name gender   salary
0  EMP01    ayushi      F      NaN
1  EMP02     rohit      M  25000.0
2  EMP03  pranjali    NaN  27000.0
3  EMP01    ayushi      F  20000.0
4  EMP05       NaN      M  25000.0
5  EMP06     rohit      M      NaN
6  EMP02     rohit      M  25000.0

now i want to remove the row number 0 because we have the same eeid in row 3 .
I ran this command but it is keeping the first row and deleting the second one .
print(data.drop_duplicates(subset=["EEID"]))

I am getting this result
    EEID      Name gender   salary
0  EMP01    ayushi      F      NaN
1  EMP02     rohit      M  25000.0
2  EMP03  pranjali    NaN  27000.0
4  EMP05       NaN      M  25000.0
5  EMP06     rohit      M      NaN

But in real I have to remove the 0 row and keep the third one

You can use groupby.last. It will get the last element in each group, and skip any NaN by default:
df = df.groupby("EEID").last()

           Name gender   salary
EEID                           
EMP01    ayushi      F  20000.0
EMP02     rohit      M  25000.0
EMP03  pranjali   None  27000.0
EMP05      None      M  25000.0
EMP06     rohit      M      NaN


I also had this in mind initially. However, since one is only considering EEID as ID, be aware that this might mix up data in rows if you have different values in Name/gender. Might not be an issue here, but it's important to be aware of it to avoid hidden bugs.

@mozway Good point.

IIUC, you could use a groupby.idxmax on the boolean Series df['salary'].notna():
out = df.loc[df['salary'].notna().groupby(df['EEID'], sort=False).idxmax()]

Output:
    EEID      Name gender   salary
3  EMP01    ayushi      F  20000.0
1  EMP02     rohit      M  25000.0
2  EMP03  pranjali    NaN  27000.0
4  EMP05       NaN      M  25000.0
5  EMP06     rohit      M      NaN

Intermediates (sorted by EEID for clarity):
    EEID      Name gender   salary  notna idxmax
0  EMP01    ayushi      F      NaN  False       
3  EMP01    ayushi      F  20000.0   True      X
1  EMP02     rohit      M  25000.0   True      X
6  EMP02     rohit      M  25000.0   True       
2  EMP03  pranjali    NaN  27000.0   True      X
4  EMP05       NaN      M  25000.0   True      X
5  EMP06     rohit      M      NaN  False      X

variant
You could also set the NaNs to 0 (of -Inf) and get the groupby.idxmax on the salary, if there are two non-NaN salaries, this will pick the highest:
out = df.loc[df['salary'].fillna(0).groupby(df['EEID'], sort=False).idxmax()]


You can sort the DF so that rows with non-null salary come before rows with null salary for the same EEID and drop the duplicates, keeping the first occurrence.
data_sorted = data.sort_values(by=['EEID', 'salary'], na_position='last').reset_index(drop=True)
result = data_sorted.drop_duplicates(subset=['EEID'], keep='first').reset_index(drop=True)

Output:
    EEID      Name gender   salary
0  EMP01    ayushi      F  20000.0
1  EMP02     rohit      M  25000.0
2  EMP03  pranjali    NaN  27000.0
3  EMP05       NaN      M  25000.0
4  EMP06     rohit      M      NaN


This works how I wanted, Thankyou

just one question..  in the first line where we are sorting (((by=['EEID','salary']))) can I give all the columns ? instead of just salary ? Like here are just 4 columns . but with big data, is there any operation which can see all the nan values in every column and sort accordingly?

Yes, I think you can. Let try by=data.columns.tolist() and see what happened? What did you mean by "see all the nan values in every column"??

drop_duplicates defaults to keep the first row in the subset. You can explicitly tell it to keep the last one instead:
print(data.drop_duplicates(subset=["EEID"], keep="last"))


can I not filter out wth any where type of condition ? I am starting out with pandas so i don't know much . like in some cases if the data willl be big then we can put the condition that if eeid is same so keep the slaary with column adn remove the NaN row?
